# Separar una columna en varias SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Alguien sabe como dividir un campo en varias columnas?

Tengo una sp, el cual me arroja la siguiente información.

Quisiera dividir el campo de Semana en varias columnas

```
SemanaAño   Semana                  FechaInicio FechaFin    RangoFechas
58       Febrero 2017 - Semana 2    2017-02-05  2017-02-11  2017-02-05*2017-02-11
57       Febrero 2017 - Semana 1    2017-01-29  2017-02-04  2017-01-29*2017-02-04
```

Por Ejemplo que me quedara de esta forma:

```
SemanaAño   Mes     Año  Semana    No_Semana FechaInicio    FechaFin    RangoFechas
58          Febrero 2017 Semana 1      1     2017-02-05     2017-02-11 2017-02-11   2017-02-05*2017-02-11
```

Comment: Claro que si, muchas gracias. Lo acabo de hacer ¿Me podrían validar por favor?.

Comment: En la segunda tabla, Semana y No_Semana no es redundante?

Comment: Si claro, eso yo pienso, pero así lo quieren... :-(, estoy validando la solución y ahorita la comparto con el grupo. Gracias.

Comment: Bueno, el cliente manda hahaha Mira mi respuesta a ver si te sirve (sobre todo de orientación ya que no puedo probarlo ahora mismo y hasta dentro de 14h no podré minimo)

Comment: MMmmm, lo que no les comente que tal vez sea la duda, es que el Mes es variable. La cadena de "Semana n" dentro del campo Semana es fijo pero el numero no.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, me ayudaron mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion que buscas es `Substring()`

```
SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Semana,1,CHARINDEX(' ', Semana)-1)) AS Mes, 
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Semana,CHARINDEX(' ', Semana) + 1, (CHARINDEX('-', Semana) -1)-(CHARINDEX(' ', Semana) + 1)) ) AS Año, 
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Semana, CHARINDEX('-', Semana)+1, LEN(@Semana))) AS Semana
FROM 
    table_name;
```

**Explicacion**

`RTRIM` -> hace un `trim` para quitar espacios al principio o final del String

`SUBSTRING` -> Coge una parte de `"Febrero 2017 - Semana 2"` pasandole donde empieza a coger y cuantos carateres.

- dentro de substring usamos `CHARINDEX` que devuelve la posicion de un `char`. Lo uso para decirle al `substring` desde donde hasta donde corta.

Con estas funciones en el select voy creando las columnas Mes, Año y Semana a partir de la semana de tu tabla.

**Nota:** Pruebalo en fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/10335/0

Comment: la forma correcta y probada de tu codigo seria para el caso de Ric_hc:   

SELECT 
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Semana,1,CHARINDEX(' ', Semana)-1)) AS Mes,
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Semana,CHARINDEX(' ', Semana) + 1, (CHARINDEX('-', Semana) -1)-(CHARINDEX(' ', Semana) + 1)) ) AS Año,
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Semana, CHARINDEX('-', Semana)+1, LEN(@Semana)))AS Semana

Comment: @JesusRodríguez gracias Jesús! edita mi respuesta para que esté bien. si no, la edito yo mañana cuando pruebe. Un saludo

Comment: Ya quedo la respuesta editada y con fiddel para acceder a una prueba rapida del codigo, Saludos

Comment: @JesusRodríguez acabo de conectarme al ordenador. El fiddle me sale en blanco :/

Comment: Vi lo mismo, afortunadamente tengo el query guardado y lo regenere en el mismo fiddle ahora solo me dio un enlace adicional el cual actualice en la publicacion. Saludos